# Finding start date of the each week php

Tags: php

Suppose there are 10 weeks; week_1st, week_2nd, week_3rd ... , week_10th. week_10th starts at 2014-05-01 00:00:00 , how can i find the start date of week_5th (the past week) ? would you please show me in php ? thank you very much.

Comment: How about adding 7 days? A week is 7 days on Earth (these days)

Comment: Depends. Are you sure that the first date (2014-05-01) is the beginning of the week? This is a Thursday.. Do you want the Monday of the 2nd week? Do you want the Thursday of the second week?

Comment: it doesn't matter what day each week will start, it can be monday , tuesday or thirsday. however if the week_10th starts at date 2014-05-01 00:00:00 , so what is the start date of the week_5th ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go exactly 5 weeks back (or something), try:

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-05-01');
$date->modify('-5 weeks');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you want to always get the monday (or similar) you can try

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-05-01');
$day = (int)$date->format('w');
$date->modify('-5 weeks');
$date->modify( 1 - $day . ' days'); // 1 = Monday
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: For the second part of your answer, another way of doing it is using `strtotime("5 mondays ago", $dateint)`

Comment: Interesting... I did not know that was possible. In the interests of keeping the answer OOP, it should be noted that `$date->modify('5 mondays ago')` will also work.